# ISO and Password Security

Tags: password-management, nist

I have to go through background check. The company providing the service to the client is called Verifications, Inc. Verifications, Inc claims to have a data security plan, ISO certification and US Federal clients.

I was surprised to learn the company provides a web based system and sends the username and password via plain text email to external systems. For example, the company will send invitation emails to an AOL or Mindspring account.

I know emailing the password violates NIST practices. For example, it violates SP800-53's Authenticator Management IA-5 and possibly IA-6. It also violates handling practices of SP800-118.

Does anyone know if emailing a plain text password is acceptable practice under any ISO? Does data sensitivity affect handling under the ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO/IEC 27002:2015 Section 9) Access Controls
Subsection 9.4.2 - Secure logon procedures

*"Implementing and using suitable authentication techniques, not disclosing sensitive information at log-on time, data entry validation, protection against brute-force attacks, logging, **not transmitting passwords in clear over the network**, session inactivity timeouts, and access time restrictions."*

Comment: Note though that that is from 27002, not 27001, and companies get certified against 27001. It is possible (providing you have a good reason and can back it up) to be certified while not implementing some of the controls suggested in 27002.